# TypeScript generics, hoist function return type

Tags: typescript

I am slowly but surely migrating my codebase to typescript but I am unable to somehow infer the return type of a callable to its parent wrapper. The functions are stripped for clarity. Take a look:

```
// component.ts
export function Component(name, factory, defaults = {}) {
    return (elem, properties) => {
        try {
            let instance = factory(elemental, settings) || {};
        } catch(error) {
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now, I use this function to register the 'clickProxy' component:

```
// clickProxy.ts
export default Component('clickProxy', (component, settings) => {
    component.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelector(settings.target)?.click();
    })

    return {
        customReturnType: true
    }
})
```

But now if I do the following, the type `{customReturnType: boolean}` is not inferred (this is the part where I will need generics or some other solution).

```
// index.ts
import clickProxy from 'clickProxy';

let nonInferred = clickProxy(document, {
    target: '#random'
});

// nonInferred will be `{customReturnType: true}`
```

Any help / resources are greatly appreciated (as the TypeScript docs do not say anything about how to use generics in combination with callables).

Comment: it would be easier if you share code that can be compiled in TS playground

Comment: okay, let me do that for you

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I found the way eventually, which results in my code looking as follows. I added a type that I pass when initializing the component:

```
export interface ResponsiveComponentResult {
    pause?(): void;
    resume?(): void;
    destroy?(): void;
}

type ComponentCallable<T = ResponsiveComponentResult> = (component, settings?: any) => T

export function <Type extends ResponsiveComponentResult = ResponsiveComponentResult>
Component(name: string, factory: ComponentCallable, defaults: Object = {}): (elem: HTMLElement, properties?: Object) => Type {
    return (elem, properties): Type => {
        try {
            let instance = factory(elemental, settings);
            return instance;
        } catch(error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows me to do the following now:

```
interface ClickProxyComponent {
    customReturnType: boolean;
}

export default Component<ClickProxyComponent>('clickProxy', (component, settings) => {
    component.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelector(settings.target)?.click();
    })

    return {
        customReturnType: true
    }
})
```

Which will infer the correct types.